# How can I watermark my own videos?

Tags: software-rec, video-editing, copyright

I was watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIFNLDQU0VQ and the first thing I noticed was the small watermark in the upper left corner.

What (open source/free) software allows one to do that? I'd very much like to watermark my gameplay videos, since I do a lot of them.

*VirtualDub > Filters > Logo* seems to work very well.

Comment: What do you use to shrink/encode them?  What format are the videos in, and what would the final source be?

Comment: VirtualDub, AVI container. H.264 for Video, Lame MP3 for Audio.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, a full step-by-step guide with free software that explains you how:

[VIDEOHelp: Put a custom watermark on your video](http://forum.videohelp.com/topic248307.html)

Comment: easy, lads   :)

Comment: @Tom, very easy to solve: just delete you answer, ephilip was quicker. and you better be quick, before you get two more downvotes, or the next badge you earn won't be a nice one :)

Comment: What's this????
Somebody tried to HELP writing an answer, the phone rings, he puts the caller on hold, posts the message and two minutes later is insulted by a child hysterically pointing out HE WAS FIRST!!! and ... what? an admin? threatening him? 
Is this a forum to help or just show of and insult people??
TomWij, my sympathy goes with you.

Comment: true enough, Wolf. although we don't necessarily need duplicate answers, ephilip's reaction is uncalled for.

Comment: Geezz, we discovered this post around the same time, I compared some links to see what's best for the question, took time to type out my post and ended up four minutes later. But yeah, he was first! I didn't think of deleting my post, and will do so tomorrow. No need to downvote me because it looks like I copied his answer, don't either upvote me because I was not the first to provide an unique answer. Sorry for this mess...

Comment: Please accept Tom's answer.  We both linked to the same thing, and it was only 4 minutes.  I have deleted my answer, and I hope yours gets accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently use Windows Movie Maker to add watermarks to videos.
See this article : [Watermark in Windows Movie Maker](http://discussions.texasbowhunter.com/forums/showthread.php?t=26954), and make sure to read the comments as well.
I haven't done this myself, so can't vouch for the process, but there are many testimonies to it on google.